# Show callout bubble without user interaction

Tags: iphone

How to show callout bubble without the user tapping on the pin ??

Answer (score 5):

(Assuming you're talking about annotations on MKMapView)

Call `[mapView selectAnnotation:yourAnnotation animated:YES];` with your annotation object

Comment: but how to get yourAnnotation here

Comment: @suresh, yourAnnotation is annotation you want to select - how to get it depends on your context...

Comment: But i am not able to find it.. can u please check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664125/show-map-callout-through-code-in-iphone

Answer (score 1):

It can be done as Vladimir said, but I think you need to do it after the MKAnnotationView related to your annotation is shown.

You can use the method below (which is a method defined in MKMapViewDelegate) to get informed when an annotation view is added to your MKMapView:

> -(void) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views

So, basically you need to invoke the method mentioned by Vladimir

> [mapView selectAnnotation:yourAnnotation animated:YES];

in the implementation of the delegate method I mentioned above

Comment: how to get yourAnnotation here?