# show map callout through code in iPhone

Tags: iphone, annotations, mkmapview, callouts

I have tried several things but am unable to solve it out.

I have 10 custom annotations on the map depending upon the area visible.

Now I have 2 buttons next and previous. Clicking on which the callout of annotation must get displayed.

i.e if i click on next buton then callout of annotation 1 will appear and when i click next again then the callout of first will hide and callout of second will appear.

I have tried out

```
[self.mapView selectAnnotation:self.nextSelectedAnnotationView.annotation animated:YES]
```

and

```
[self.mapView deselectAnnotation:self.selectedAnnotationView.annotation animated:YES];
```

But the main problem is how to get the annotation here??

I have tried `NSArray* selectedAnnotations=self.mapview.annotations` to get the annotations array

```
id annotationView =[selectedAnnotations objectAtIndex:i];
[self.mapView selectAnnotation:annotationView animated:YES];
```

But no luck :(

Any other way to solve my issue.??

Comment: You mean -selectAnnotation:animated:, not -deselect..., right?

Comment: you mean you have to open automatically one by one annotation?

Comment: @caleb: I have tried with both. Take the case that my first callout is opened now when i click on next button the first one will get deselect and second one's selected will get called

Answer (score 0):

it may help you.

```
 NSArray *selectedAnnotations = mapView.selectedAnnotations;
for(id annotationView in selectedAnnotations) {
    [mapView deselectAnnotation:[annotationView annotation] animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: It wont open up the callout for next annotation :(